# Django choose version to upgrade

Tags: django, upgrade

We're currently on django 1.9 and we want to upgrade to newer version of django.
We don't know how to choose version to upgrade, since 1.11 is LTS and could be easier to upgrade and 2.0 is not LTS but later it will be easier to upgrade to 2.x LTS.
Could you please give us some hints?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest moving to 1.11 since with 2.** there are radical changes and some others that can break your codes. Read the release note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/) for 1.11 and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) for 2.*

To install the one needed, just type the command `pip install -U package_name` followed `==version` where version could be 1.11 or 2.0.

In your case, the package name is `Django`, let's do it with `pip`

```
pip install -U django==1.11
#or
pip install --upgrade django==1.11
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need to know which version to choose. 1.11 or 2.0.

Comment: I suggest moving to 1.11 since with 2.** there are radical changes and some others that can break your codes. Read the release note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/) for 1.11 and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) for 2.*

Comment: Thank you. We decided to migrate to 1.11, since 2.0 is not LTS and it's a better practice to migrate to only LTS versions. If you edit the answer and provide your comment in the answer I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @AliFarhoudi  Actually you should first migrate to 1.10, fix everything that needs fixing, then migrate to 1.11.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers. Based on our experiment migrating to target version at once needs more reconstruction, but it will be just one time and it takes less time to fix it.